# Someone swam ashore

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does

> someone swam ashore

mean?

Does it mean

1. Someone who swimming in the sea tries to reach to the land.
2. Someone is swimming near the land or beach or ashore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means someone who swims to shore. Swam ashore is the same thing.

Comment: so my first explanations is correct then

Comment: Not exactly. It is not an attempt. If you swim ashore, you actually get to the shore. And it can be in a lake or river, too. Again: it is not trying to do it. It's actually getting to the shore. In other words, it is not: swim towards shore.

Comment: so when you swam ashore, people who are standing or laying  at the shore can see your full body.

Comment: You are swimming. Obviously, once you reach the shore, you then stand up. You can also row ashore, in a rowboat. ashore replaces **to shore**.

Answer (score 0):

***[Ashore](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/ashore)*** means:

> towards or onto land from an area of water:
>
> - We swam ashore.
> - A few pieces of wood had washed ashore.
> - Strong winds blew the ship ashore.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Actually this is where I inspired to ask the question because I could not understand it at that time.